# Find the Fourier series of $f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}(a_k\cos{kx} + b_k\sin{kx})$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm learning about Fourier series and need help with this problem:

> Find the Fourier series of
>   $$
> f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}(a_k\cos{kx} + b_k\sin{kx})
> $$

---

**My thoughts:**

The above trigonometric polynomial is the nth partial sum of the Fourier series for $f$. Taking the sum to infinity we get the Fourier series of $f$. Is it that simple or am I missing something here?

Comment: Why don't you try to find the Fourier transform the usual way? Use the orthogonality of trigonometric functions.

Comment: We have not seen orthogonality of trigonometric functions yet in class. This problem can certainly be solved with another method.

Comment: This is a classic. Similar to "Find the Laurent series for $z^{-1}$ around $z=0$." -- Note that in this task, $n$ is fixed. -- If you meant $a_k=0=b_k$ for $k>n$, then your statement is correct.

Comment: Ok, then you should convince yourself that this already is in the appropriate form, i.e. the function $f(x)$ is expressed as a Fourier series. It just has a finite number of coefficients. If you would formally calculate its Fourier series, you would get the identical form of $f(x)$.

Comment: @LutzL The analogy withe the Laurent series of $z^{-1}$ was indeed helpful, thank you. I'm still having difficulties to convince myself that the function $f(x)$ is already in the appropriate form. All of the examples that we have seen in class had an infinite sum, the fact that the sum is finite here is disturbing me.

Comment: That's because such functions do not often arise in Fourier analysis. The idea of Fourier series is that you can take a function and represent it as a sum of sines and cosines. And for the most functions, you need the sum to be infinite, i.e. you need the sines and cosines of every period. Consider the function $f(x)=\sin x$. What is its Fourier series? Well it's just $f(x)=\sin x$, i.e. $a_1=1$ and all other coefficients are zero. Same goes for $f(x)=5\sin 4x+\cos (2x)$ and any linear combination of sines and cosines, of which your function is an example.

Comment: @eyedropper Thank you for your helpful explanation. It is very clear and understandable. Since the Fourier series is identical to $f$, is it correct to say that the Fourier series converges uniformly to $f$?

Comment: Well since $f(x)=S(x)$, where $S(x)$ is the Fourier series of $f(x)$, I would say yes. Let $S_N(x)$ be the partial Fourier series, then for $N\geq n$ you will have $f(x)=S_N(x)$ and therefore $|f(x)-S_N(x)|=0<\epsilon $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the orthogonality of trigonometric functions I meant the following identities

$$
\begin{align}
\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }\sin (nx)\sin (mx)\mathrm{d}x&=\pi \delta _{m,n}\\
\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }\cos (nx)\cos (mx)\mathrm{d}x&=\pi \delta _{m,n}\\
\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }\sin (nx)\cos (mx)\mathrm{d}x&=0
\end{align}
$$
which can be easily verified by using basic trigonometric identities, such as product-to-sum formulas. Let 
$$f(x)=\frac{c_0}{2}+\sum _{m=1}^{+\infty }(c_m\cos (mx)+d_m\sin (mx))$$
be the Fourier series of $f$. Then the coefficients for your $f(x)$ satisfy

$$
\begin{align}
c_m&=\frac{1}{\pi }\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }f(x)\cos (mx)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum _{k=1}^{n }\left(a_k\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }\cos (kx)\cos (mx)\mathrm{d}x+b_k\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }\sin (kx)\cos (mx)\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum _{k=1}^{n }\left(a_k \cdot \pi \delta _{k,m}+b_k\cdot 0\right)=a_m \text{ for $m\leq n$ and 0 otherwise}
\end{align}$$

The same goes for $c_0=a_0$ and $d_m=b_m$ and this proves explicitly that the Fourier series of $f(x)$ is $f(x)$. The $\delta $ symbol is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation. It was extremely helpful and understandable. It also gave me another way of thinking about this problem.